# Unity no cambia las escenas

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d, motor-de-juego

En mi proyecto de Unity tengo estas dos escenas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tenía este código para cambiar de escena con un trigger:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    //DETECTA TRIGGER PARA ENTRAR A CASA
    if(other.gameObject.name.Equals("casa")){
        Application.LoadLevel("casa");
    }

    //DETECTA TRIGGER SALIR DE CASA
    if(other.gameObject.name.Equals("salirDeCasa")){
        Application.LoadLevel("escenalibre");
    }
}
```

Con este código funcionaba perfectamente, pero al dia siguiente abrí el proyecto y ya no cambiaba las escenas y buscando por Google encontre esta otra forma de hacerlo:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    //DETECTA TRIGGER PARA ENTRAR A CASA
    if(other.gameObject.name.Equals("casa")){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("casa",LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }

    //DETECTA TRIGGER SALIR DE CASA
    if(other.gameObject.name.Equals("salirDeCasa")){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("escenalibre",LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Y añadiendole el `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`.

Pues bien, tampoco me funciona... Pero si decido cambiar por la propia escena en la que estoy en ese momento, si se cambia por si misma, es como si estando en una escena no detectara las demás...

¿Alguien sabe si esto tiene solución? ¿O si es que he cometido un error en el código?

Comment: @PabloLozano Si eso no esta muy bien, disculpas, no obstante he comprobado si entraba en los IF con un Debug.Log y si que entra, no se que ocurre la verdad...

Comment: Te has asegurado de añadir las escenas en el build?

Comment: @HectorLopez Si era eso, muchas gracias! Como ya sin tocar nada la primera vez me funcionó no tuve en cuenta eso...

Answer (score 1):

Fijate que las escenas esten seeccionadas y habilitadas en el Build Settings, incluso en el editor pide tener las escenas indizadas para poder cambiar entre ellas.